# How to get calendar invites to come in as iCal and not as Google Calendar invites?

Tags: icloud, calendar, gmail, ical, google-calendar

I use my Gmail email-address as my Apple ID. When people send me calendar invites, I only receive them on Google Calendar. And since I deactivated the calendar on my Macs for Gmail account, I don't get notified at all (besides an email).

Is there a way to receive the invitations on iCal instead? Or do I have to use a non-Google address as my Apple ID?

Comment: Same problem for me, but I don't get any notification, not even email.  Is there a setting to get emails for every new invitation?

Answer (score 2):

> Or do I have to use a non-Google address as my Apple ID?

No, you need not change or create a new Apple ID. A calendar invite sent to an email address registered with Gmail will automatically get added to Google Calendar. Also, it won't automatically get added in Apple Calendar.

You can do subscribe to your Google Calendar in macOS Calendar app. The instructions to subscribe can be found in the following links:

- https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/37648
- https://support.apple.com/kb/HT202361

However, it is not possible to get the calendar invite via Apple ID in iCloud calendar.

Comment: I know that. But I want to receive the notifications in iCal directly. Is that possible?

Comment: @ØleBjarnstroem Yes, that's possible. Updated the answer.

Comment: That I also already did. But I want them to be in my iCloud calendar from my Apple ID, not on Google calendar that I subscribed to.

Comment: @ØleBjarnstroem That won't be possible.