# How to get calendar invites to come in as iCal when i use a gmail address as my appleID?

Tags: icloud, calendar, gmail, ical

I use *myname*@gmail.com for my appleid username. If i wish to send an invite to my icloud calendar, how can i do so? I have *myname*@icloud.com and *myname*@me.com email addresses that are associated with my appleID (contactable at). I have tried sending the invite to these addresses but nothing has been received. Any ideas how i can send an invite to my icloud calendar?

Note this is a different question to "[How to get calendar invites to come in as iCal and not as Google Calendar invites?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/342623/151404)" That asks how to get invites sent to a gmail address show up in ical without adding a gmail calendar. I am happy to send the invite to a non-gmail address.

Comment: Can you clarify how you're attempting to send calendar invites? I believe you should be able to accept ical invites sent to your apple email (myname@gmail.com). I would test by using somebody else's device to create an ical event and then inviting myname@gmail.com

Comment: I am sending the invite from an outlook exchange account at my ace of work.

Comment: My best guess is that you'll have to change your Apple ID to your icloud email to have this work properly. I personally just have my google calendar connected. Would also be interested in a more seamless solution.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the solution is to force iCloud to send you invitations by email. Most people complain when they are inviting Gmail users from iCloud calendars, but I believe you're having the same problem.

1. Log into iCloud.com
2. Select Calendar
3. Click Gear Icon, elect
4. Select Advanced Tab
5. Select radio button for "send email to [your primary iCloud email]"

iCloud tries to handle invites "behind the scenes" when the invited email address is connected to an iCloud account. Does this work for you?[image]